# Modulus Query in Django using F()

Tags: python, django, modulus

I want to filter for Django objects such that their "id modulo K == N" .

Here's a way to do it in python, but I want it in the filter():

```
for foo in Foo.objects.all():
  if foo.id % K == N:
    print foo
```

So, I can use extra() with a query like this (please correct me if I'm wrong):

> Foo.objects.extra(where['id %% %s = %s' % (K,N)])

But is there a way to use [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F)?

> Django supports the use of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and modulo arithmetic with F() objects

Note: this is very wrong:

> Foo.objects.filter(id=F('id') % K)

I would need something like:

> Foo.objects.filter(id__mod(K)=N)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django 1.8 allows you to use F() objects in annotations. The syntax is:

```
Foo.objects.annotate(id_mod=F('id') % K).filter(id_mod=n)
```

The feature was implemented in [#14030](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030). For earlier versions of Django, you can use `extra()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about what filter is trying to do, it's taking an attribute and performing a comparison.  You aren't actually comparing `id` to anything, but rather are filtering based off a calculated value.  `extra` is the most appropriate way to perform this calculation-based filtering despite it sounding like `filter` would be able to do that.